# Passing value for listview to textbox on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

My list view has a link button:

Aspx:

```
 <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <tr style="background-color:#FFF8DC;">

                    <td>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="CaseNumberLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CaseNumber") %>'  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CaseNumber") %>' OnCommand="lkbCommandAction_Command"  />
                    </td>
```

C#

```
     protected void lkbCommandAction_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
        TextBox1.Text = 
    }
```

How can I pass the value to the Textbox1.Text on click?

Comment: passing value of what  to `textbox`?

Comment: What text you are referring here?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about text of linkbutton itself then you can use the linkbutton [`Text`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.text%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to set to `TextBox` like (Assuming your ListView name is `lstview1`)

```
 protected void lkbCommandAction_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
    TextBox1.Text = ((LinkButton)this.lstview1.FindControl("lkbCommandAction")).Text;
}
```

Comment: if the control is inside of a ListView, you have to first find the control in side of the dynamic control.

Comment: @BenSewards, absolutely correct. Just didn't wanted to write the whole statement. Rather thought of pointing what he is missing.

Comment: The textbox is outside of the listview in another "View" and yet I am getting the error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.. At line: TextBox1.Text = ((LinkButton)this.lstview1.FindControl("lkbCommandAction")).Text;